# How send sms from websites using asp.net c# without third party sms gate way

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, gsm

I use in website two fields txtmono and txtmsg and one button btnsend. I want to send sms under button btnsend. I use one GSM Modem (3G).

Thanks.........

Comment: Please post ur code. Nobody will try to help with out proper question with explanation.

Comment: the SMS is a command that you must send to the server of the SMS handling, if you have a server like that you probably know how to do it, if not, then you need some other gateway - with other words, you can not send sms with out a gateway server that handles it.

Answer (score 3):

Either you would have to host your own website, or you would have to get the notifictions to send SMSes sent to you in real time.

You would also need a SIM with an account with a mobile operator that lets you send SMS, bearing in mind that normal customer accounts aren't designed for commercial use.

The actual SMS sending can be done via commands on Windows Mobile Broadband API (assuming you're on Windows 7+) or AT commands sent to the modem port if you're on another OS.

But a single 3G modem can't send a big volume of SMSes over the radio interface anyway.  It is not suitable for any commercial application.  That's why there are gateways that get bulk SMSes via the internet and feed them directly into the messaging centre in the mobile network via an IP connection.

I don't know what the purpose of your website is, but using your own modem is unlikely to meet your needs.